# The pattern on Stern-Gerlach experiment

Tags: quantum-spin

[image]

I got this picture from following site.

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/spin.html

See two red circles I added. Two patterns are same.

1. Is it wrong drawing? (pattern in right red circle)
2. Is their any experiment data showing the patterns for various distances from magnet to screen(Photographic plate)? I want to check if the pattern smaller or not when the screen closer to magnet.

Comment: The red circle on the right is wrong.

Comment: If you look up the source (Beiser) you see that originally the smudge on the right was simply a slit